# Styling error in default browsers of Samsung and Apple, Chrome works fine

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

The mobile page of http://www.ergotopia.de/ergonomie-shop/ergonomische-kissen/orthopaedisches-sitzkissen should look like the right (how it is in inspection of chrome) but on smartphone default browser it looks like left. On Smartphone Chrome browser it looks normal as well, but most people use default browsers unfortunately.

[image]

I tried to effect the weird looking class "product-info" with following, but without any change. Do you know whats wrong here?

```
.product-info { 
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

Or is there any opportunity to try in inspection mode on mobile?

Comment: I checked on a few different Chrome devices i have and I didnt see the issue you have in the screenshot above. Everything looked good.

Comment: yes it looks good on chrome, but not on default browsers of Samsung and Apple. Because they have their own browsers

Comment: FYI you have heigh for images, it should be height, fix your code errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?acceptlanguage=&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ergotopia.de%2Fergonomie-shop%2Fergonomische-kissen%2Forthopaedisches-sitzkissen

Comment: thank you, good to know this tool, I will check every site with this today.

Comment: I'm using iOS 11 beta 4 and the page displays fine. If you have a Mac, you can connect Safari's inspector to the iPhone's browser: http://robandlauren.com/2013/09/14/test-on-devices/

Comment: allright, then I propably have an older version. But on every Samsung its looking quite weird like in the picture and I have no idea how to fix that. But there are a lot of Samsung users out there.

Comment: @KrystianManthey , can you change the `meta tag` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and check. I had once this type of issue.

Comment: @KrystianManthey I could not reproduce this issue in the Samsung Browser on a Galaxy S5, S6, S7 or S8 via BrowserStack - or in iOS 10. Can you advise on what phone you're using? I'd also contest that "most people use default browsers" over Chrome on Samsung phones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a possible way to remotely debug Samsung Internet via Chrome `chrome://inspect`with this manual: https://samsunginter.net/docs/remote-debugging

Out of some reason I cannot get it work. I followed the manual but there is no such link like highlighted here:
[image]

Is it working on your desktop?

**I couldnt find a solution to inspect Samsung Internet Browser, but I was able to fix the weird looking problem with giving the boxes a `min-width:100%` 
Dont really know why this is now working, but it does**

Comment: This way only for inspect debug app. That mean if you app is built for production, it can not be inspected